# Android different rows in listview

Tags: android, listview, row

i have news application that download data from web and displays it in listview ,but how can i make that first row is different ,bigger height ,different layout and stuff ?

this is main activity source

```
public class Home extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://dmb.site50.net/application.php?app_access_key=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    public static final String TAG_NEWS = "news";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TAG_STORY = "story";
    public static final String TAG_SH_STORY = "shorten";
    public static final String TAG_DATETIME = "datetime";
    public static final String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
    public static final String TAG_IMG = "img";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;
    Button mBtnNaslovnica;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mBtnNaslovnica = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnNaslovnica);
        mBtnNaslovnica.setSelected(true);
        TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    txtView.setSelected(true);

        ImageButton mBtnRefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        mBtnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new LoadingTask().execute(URL);
            }
        });


            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> homeList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



                JSONObject jsonobj;
                try {
                    jsonobj = new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
                    JSONArray news = jsonobj.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String story = c.getString(TAG_STORY);
                        String shorten = c.getString(TAG_SH_STORY);
                        String author = c.getString(TAG_AUTHOR);
                        String datetime = c.getString(TAG_DATETIME);
                        String img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        map.put(TAG_STORY, story);
                        map.put(TAG_IMG, img);
                        map.put(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);
                        map.put(TAG_AUTHOR, author);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        homeList.add(map);}
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }






            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, homeList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    String cur_title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                    String cur_story = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.einfo2)).getText().toString();
                    String cur_author = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.einfo1)).getText().toString();
                    String cur_datetime  = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.einfo)).getText().toString();
                    ImageView cur_img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                    String cur_img_url = (String) cur_img.getTag();

                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.androidhive.CURENTNEWS");
                    i.putExtra("CUR_TITLE", cur_title);
                    i.putExtra("CUR_STORY", cur_story);
                    i.putExtra("CUR_AUTHOR", cur_author);
                    i.putExtra("CUR_DATETIME", cur_datetime);
                    i.putExtra("CUR_IMG_URL", cur_img_url);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });     
        }   

    public void loadPage(){

    }

    public void startNewActivity(){

    }
    public class LoadingTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object>{
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String URL = params[0];
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            //String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
             // getting DOM element
            return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
            Intent startApp = new Intent("com.example.androidhive.HOME");
            startApp.putExtra("json", result.toString());
            startActivity(startApp);
        }


    }



    }
```

Comment: **how can i make that first row is different ,bigger height ,different layout and stuff ?** If its only for First Row then use Header View with ListView and skip first row (view) in your Custom Adapter's getView() .. Simple.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your `LazyAdapter` code to return right layout for each row, depending on any criteria you want. ListView simply uses view given by adapter, so it is nothing special to have each row layouted differently. Please note that to make it work correctly you need to implement `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` as well.