# Android listview first row

Tags: android, listview, row, adapter

I have news application that needs to download data from the url and display it in listview , but i want first row to be diferent from others because in there will be displayed main news lets say , i have this adapter class to display all rows same , and i cant modify it in order to do what i wrote above , can anybody help me

here is the code of adapter class

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}



public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    //TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView author = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo1); // duration
    TextView datetime = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo);
    TextView story = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.einfo2);
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> n = new HashMap<String, String>();
    n = data.get(position);


    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_TITLE));
    author.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_AUTHOR));
    datetime.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_DATETIME));
    story.setText(n.get(Home.TAG_STORY));
    thumb_image.setTag(n.get(Home.TAG_IMG));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(n.get(Home.TAG_IMG), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android different rows in listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226465/android-different-rows-in-listview)

Comment: Do you see my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this UI Pattern, that's very cool :)

I think it's write for you : https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh

Answer (score 1):

AliSh answer is a good one. It gives you a good look. However if you wish to keep it simple, then try this. 
In the getView() method,

```
if(position==0)
{
    // do stuff for your headline
}
else
{
    // do other stuff
}
```

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ListView`s [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) method to add a custom View at the top.